# Capistrano deployment failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rvm, capistrano

Im having some problems getting capistrano to deploy.

As far as i can tell the fail happens with the git ls-remote command, but when i run it on the server manually it returns successfully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**SOLVED**

After installing mountain lion my git cli wasn't working.

---

```
cap deploy
    triggering load callbacks
  * 15:55:49 == Currently executing `staging'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
  * 15:55:49 == Currently executing `multistage:ensure'
  * 15:55:49 == Currently executing `deploy'
  * 15:55:49 == Currently executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 15:55:49 == Currently executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:taheilo/taheilo.com.git master"
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/frankie/sites/taheilo.com/stage/releases/20120726135550; true"
    servers: ["198.101.205.147"]
    [198.101.205.147] executing command
    command finished in 2039ms
/Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:107:in ``': No such file or directory - git ls-remote git@github.com:taheilo/taheilo.com.git master (Errno::ENOENT)
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:107:in `block in run_locally'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:106:in `run_locally'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:44:in `block (3 levels) in load'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:96:in `with_env'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in load'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/git.rb:227:in `query_revision'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/base.rb:35:in `block in method_missing'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/base.rb:63:in `local'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/base.rb:35:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:44:in `block in load'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:87:in `call'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:87:in `block in fetch'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:110:in `block in protect'
  from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:110:in `protect'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:78:in `fetch'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:95:in `[]'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/base.rb:82:in `revision'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/remote_cache.rb:35:in `update_repository_cache'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/remote_cache.rb:15:in `deploy!'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:222:in `block (2 levels) in load'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:139:in `instance_eval'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:139:in `invoke_task_directly'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:193:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:203:in `block (3 levels) in load'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:56:in `transaction'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:193:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:202:in `block (2 levels) in load'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:139:in `instance_eval'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:139:in `invoke_task_directly'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:193:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:170:in `block (2 levels) in load'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:139:in `instance_eval'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:139:in `invoke_task_directly'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:46:in `block in execute_requested_actions'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `each'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `execute_requested_actions'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/help.rb:19:in `execute_requested_actions_with_help'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:34:in `execute!'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/cap:19:in `load'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/cap:19:in `<main>'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
  from /Users/frankie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to execute it locally as capistrano says:

```
executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:taheilo/taheilo.com.git master"
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out after installing Mountain Lion my git cli got messed up.

Comment: ah, good that you mentioned ML upgrade - always helps to know what to expect :)